# Get the start index and end index of a regexp match

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/KRrb9/7/

```
<textarea>* this is a bold string * this is not a bold string </textarea>
<button> match! </button>

$('button').bind('click', function(){
    var match = $('textarea').val().match(/(.)+/);
    console.log(match);
});
```

The above `match.index` returns the position of the first letter of the match, which is `0` as the match matches the whole string.

How can I get the end of the match? I thought it would be simple, but sadly the match object only contains the start index of the match :(

```
["* this is a bold string * this is not a bold string ", " ", index: 0, input: "* this is a bold string * this is not a bold string "]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string will be `match[0].length` characters long, add that onto your start to get the ending index:

```
$('button').bind('click', function(){
    var match = $('textarea').val().match(/([a-z]+)/);
    console.log( match.index + match[0].length );
});
```

Comment: Should it actually be `match.index + match[0].length - 1` because the index is from 0 but the length is from 1, as it were?